# Can promises be used to trigger a bunch of async loads?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

I'm having problmes in finding the use of promises and also admit that my understanding of them is very basic.  From what I can tell, they just seem to mimic sync behavior.

Is it possible to use promises and keep the async behaviour then use then() once they have all completed?

Such as this...

```
var fileRegister = [ 'fileA', 'fileB', 'fileC' ];

for( i in fileRegister ) {
  asyncLoadFile( fileRegister[ i ], function( err, data ) {
    delete fileRegister[ i ];
    if ( ! fileRegister.length ) {
      console.log('done');
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: FYI, using `delete` on an array element does not change `.length` on the array.  It just clears that array entry.

Comment: it's half pseudocode, i've never run it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use `Promise.all` to wait on multiple promises:

```
var fileRegister = [ 'fileA', 'fileB', 'fileC' ];

// returns a promise for a file
function loadFile(filename) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        asyncLoadFile(filename, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            }
            resolve(data);
        });
    });
}

Promise.all(fileRegister.map(loadFile))
    .then(function (files) {
        console.log("done");
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm truly surpised there seems to be no authoratative answer for this on the site.  Yes, you can create a bunch of promises (each wrapping an async operation) and then call Promise,all which will resolve once they all do:

```
var p1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { 
  setTimeout(resolve, 1000, "one"); 
}); 
var p2 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { 
  setTimeout(resolve, 2000, "two"); 
});
var p3 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(resolve, 3000, "three");
});
var p4 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(resolve, 4000, "four");
});
var p5 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  reject("reject");
});

Promise.all([p1, p2, p3, p4, p5]).then(function(value) { 
  console.log(value);
}, function(reason) {
  console.log(reason)
});
```

This is part of the E^ specification and is supported by most implementations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it was very useful in helping my understanding.